How to specify where to start a list CSS
My HTML structure looks like this:
<ol styletype="A" start="5">
  <li data-prefix="Pre" data-suffix="Suf">Item 1</li>
  <li data-prefix="Pre" data-suffix="Suf">Item 2</li>
  <li data-prefix="Pre" data-suffix="Suf">Item 3</li>
</ol>

The start attribute is where I want to start the list. I was able to do the following where I was able to start the list from the number entered into the content editable list:
/* Default start value */
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

/* Custom start values */
ol[start="2"] {
  counter-reset: item 0;
}

ol[start="3"] {
  counter-reset: item 1;
}

ol[start="4"] {
  counter-reset: item 2;
}

/* Add more as needed */
ol[start="5"] {
  counter-reset: item 3;
}

/* Decimal (1, 2, 3, ...) */
ol[styletype="1"] > li::before {
  content: attr(data-prefix) "." counter(item, decimal) "." attr(data-suffix);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  counter-increment: item;
}

I can start a list from 1 - 5 no problem, however, I need a way to be able to start a list from any number, roman number, letter, etc. I want to be able to start a list from b., z., 4., 7., etc.
I tried this method:
ol[start] {
  counter-reset: item calc(attr(start, number) - 1);
}

However, it just starts every list with 2 no matter what I type.

Sounds like a job for CSS variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#ordered_list_with_a_custom_value ??

Counters or variables aren't needed, you can use the HTML start attribute and CSS list-style-type


ol.alphabet {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}

ol.roman {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
<ol start=5>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<ol start=9 class="alphabet">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
<ol start=527 class="roman">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>



